# IDS algorithm optimality for grid?

Tags: graphs, graph-traversal

My homework is implementing algorithms BFS, DFS, depth-limited and IDS for the map as a 2D grid with 8 directions of movement. 
I read that the IDS algorithm is optimal, but in my case is not optimal paths.

Is the IDS algorithm optimal for graphs (e.g. map as a grid), or does optimality only apply to searching trees?

Comment: IDS should be optimal if it's a simple grid traversal where the traveling cost is the same everywhere (see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Iterative_deepening_depth-first_search)). Maybe check your implementation?